# Does lxml supports usage of custom non-XML, non-HTML parser?

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I need to parse almost XML-like data in Python

```
[tag]text [anothertag]anothertext[/anothertag][/tag]
```

I realised that in `xml.etree.ElementTree` one can pass a custom parser to the `fromstring(string, parser)` function. Though I need to use `lxml.etree` because of `XSLT` support. I cannot pass a parser, I can only use another class instead of `Element` class, but this has nothing to do with parsing.

*Is there a way to implement my own parser for `lxml`?*

P.S. Please do not refer to "honking" example - it makes no sense to me.

P.P.S Changing `[` to `<` won't help, while the parser should work also with the input

```
[tag]text [anothertag]anothertext[/tag][/anothertag]
```

Comment: Is your input bbcode?

Comment: No, it's so-called DSL, rare format for the dictionaries http://lingvo.helpmax.net/en/troubleshooting/dsl-compiler/dsl-tags/

Comment: Ah I see. So a few of them have direct HTML counterparts, but there also are a few special ones that must be handled differently. Is the documentation exhaustive or do even more tags exist?

Comment: It's partially proprietary, or something. The link is an official source. Some other knowledge is obtained by reverse-engineering.